# Remove scrollbars from Facebook page tab app?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, facebook-apps

There are hundreds of posts about this on the internet, many of which are here on StackOverflow, but unfortunately none of the solutions mentioned seem to work for me. I have spent the better part of 6 hours tinkering with no success.

Here's what I have:

- I have created a Facebook app and added it as a Page Tab.
- I have added the app to a Facebook page here: https://www.facebook.com/pages/PARKROYAL-Darling-Harbour-Sydney/236917443012539?sk=app_195092900626979

But I cannot for the life of me set the height of the iFrame so that I can safely remove the scrollbars!

Here is the structure of my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>PARKROYAL Magic Moments</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<MAIN CODE HERE>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId : '<APP-ID>',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml : true // parse XFBML
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize( { height: 1642 } );
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize( { height: 1642 } );
}
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

In my CSS I have also set body { overflow:hidden }

Comment: Look into your browser’ error console, the message is right there …

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried [FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/). You can use it like this:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '235024806624460',
    });
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    }
 </script>
```